# AWS Redhat Chromedriver doesnt work with Java selenium

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, selenium

I am trying to create a simple `AWS` based java selenium app.

I have installed **java JDK**, and **google-chrome**

I have created a sample app which runs fine from windows (with *chrome-driver* ofc)
But when I copy the code to `AWS` and try to run I always get this error.

Any idea how to solve this?

```
[root@ip-172-31-43-139 ec2-user]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.6.11.0.74.amzn1-x86_64 u151-b00)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.151-b00, mixed mode)



[root@ip-172-31-43-139 ec2-user]# google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 60.0.3112.113
```

My sample code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        WebDriver driver = null;

//      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
        //Set up
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--screenshoot");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options); // dies here <-

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        //Tear down
        driver.quit();

    }

}
```

Console output:

```
Hello World!
/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome: symbol lookup error: /opt/google/chrome/lib/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured
Nov 06, 2017 1:44:12 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess checkForError
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 127 (Exit value: 127)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11 11:22:43'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-43-139', ip: '172.31.43.139', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.51-10.52.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
        at hu.csani.aws_test.App.setUp(App.java:33)
        at hu.csani.aws_test.App.main(App.java:19)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time: '2016-02-11 11:22:43'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-43-139', ip: '172.31.43.139', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.51-10.52.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.7.0_151'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:178)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:22678/status] to be available after 20005 ms
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:107)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:175)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedTimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:143)
        at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:80)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:201)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:130)
        ... 13 more
```

The google-chrome works fine from terminal...

Answer (score 0):

try to update your java to JAVA 8 (1.8)

Answer (score 0):

faced same issue, but with slightly different error

`SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 139 (Exit value: 139)`

Something were wrong with driver extraction from archive - right size is ~8MB

for failed

`drwxrwxr-x 2 jenkins jenkins    4096 Mar 12 10:01 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 jenkins jenkins    4096 Oct 10 10:10 ..
-rwxrw-r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 1376159 Oct 10 10:10 chromedriver`

for successful

`drwxrwxr-x 2 jenkins jenkins    4096 Oct 10 10:11 .
drwxrwxr-x 7 jenkins jenkins    4096 Oct 10 10:11 ..
-rwxrw-r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 8950080 Oct 10 10:11 chromedriver`